Geometric Sequences $A$ and $B$ with Common Ratio; Finding Missing Term in Sequence $C$
$A$ and $B$ are both geometric sequences, and the common ratio of $B$ is $1/3$. $C$ is a sequence created by adding corresponding elements if $A$ and $B$. If $C=\{ 97,51,45,m,... \}$, find the value of $m$.

For sequence $A$, we have:
$A=\{ a, ar, ar^2, ar^3, ...\}$
For sequence $B$, we have:
$B=\{ b, \frac{b}{3}, \frac{b}{9}, \frac{b}{27}, ... \}$
Therefore, $a+b=97$, $ar+\frac{b}{3}=51$, $ar^2+\frac{b}{9}=45$, and $ar^3+\frac{b}{27}=m$.
I've managed to rewrite it into a simpler form: $a+b=97$, $3ar+b=153$, $9ar^{2}+b=405$, and $27ar^{3}+b=27m$
I've substituted $b=97-a$ into all the equations, so $3ar+97-a=153$, $9ar^{2}+97-a=405$, and $27ar^{3}+97-a=27m$
However, this approach doesn't seem to lead anywhere, as there are still two unknown variables.
Any assistance in solving for the value of $m$ would be greatly appreciated!

From $a+b=97$ and $ar+b/3=51$ we get $r=\dfrac{51-b/3}{97-b}$, and from $ar+b/3=51$ and $ar^2+b/9=45$ we get $r=\dfrac{45-b/9}{51-b/3}$.
Thus, we must have $$ \dfrac{51-b/3}{97-b}=\dfrac{45-b/9}{51-b/3}$$
Cross-multiplying we get a first degree equation with the only solution $b=81$.
From  here, $r=\dfrac{51-b/3}{97-b}=\dfrac{51-27}{16}=\dfrac{3}{2}$, and $a=97-b=16$.
As you found, we have $27ar^3+b=27m$, so $$\boxed{m=ar^3+b/27=16\left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)^3+3=57}$$
